# Angular 2 - Using Dynamic Nested Form to Edit data

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am using a nested form to enter unlimited next of kin records for each individual patient data. Working nested form:

[image]

I want the same form to be used for editing data when a user wants to edit the patient's record. However, when I do this all the other form fields are populated except for the nested section (the form array section) only the first item is picked on clicking edit:

[image]

The challenge I believe is that when using a new form I can open multiple next of kin subform using add button which calls `(click) = "addKin()"` which allows a new NextKin to be opened when clicked.

Add click function:

```
addKin() {
    const control = <FormArray>this.patientForm.controls['nextKins'];
    control.push(this.initNextKin());
  }
```

The NextKin form array is in separate component: `<next-kin></next-kin>`

```
<div class="row">
  <h5>Next of Kin Details</h5>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div formArrayName="nextKins">
           <div *ngFor="let nextKin of patientForm.controls.nextKins.controls; let i=index">
           <!-- header, show remove button when more than one kin detail is available -->
              <div>
                 Next of Kin {{i + 1}}
                 <span class="float-xs-right" *ngIf="patientForm.controls.nextKins.controls.length > 1" (click)="removeKin(i)"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>Remove</span>
                    </div>

                    <div [formGroupName]="i">
                      <next-kin [group]="patientForm.controls.nextKins.controls[i]" ></next-kin>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <button type="button" (click)="addKin()">
                Add another next of kin
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
```

How can I open a new NextKin subform when selecting a record to Edit? I have tried looping through the input data but only get the first nextKin record (index 0 in the nextKins array) to show.

part of the patient-form component

```
configureForm(patient?: Patient) {
    if (patient) {
      this.currentPatient = new Patient(
        patient.$key,
        patient.registrationNo,
        patient.patientName,
        patient.gender,
        patient.birthYear,
        patient.notes,
        patient.nextKins,
        patient.createdBy,
        patient.createdDate,
        patient.updatedBy,
        patient.updatedDate
      );
    }
    this.patientForm = this._formBuilder.group({
      registrationNo: [this.currentPatient.registrationNo, [Validators.required]],
      patientName: [this.currentPatient.patientName, [Validators.required]],
      gender: [this.currentPatient.gender],
      birthYear: [this.currentPatient.birthYear, [Validators.required]],
      notes: [this.currentPatient.notes],
      nextKins: this._formBuilder.array([
        this.initNextKin(this.currentPatient.nextKins),
      ])
    });
  }

  initNextKin(patient?) {
    if (patient) {
      for (let i = 0; i < patient.length; i++) {
        return this._formBuilder.group({
          kinName: [this.currentPatient.nextKins[i]['kinName']],
          kinRelationship: [this.currentPatient.nextKins[i]['kinRelationship']],
          kinMobile: [this.currentPatient.nextKins[i]['kinMobile']],
          kinEmail: [this.currentPatient.nextKins[i]['kinEmail']]
        });
      }
    }
    return this._formBuilder.group({
      kinName: [this.currentPatient.nextKins['kinName']],
      kinRelationship: [this.currentPatient.nextKins['kinRelationship']],
      kinMobile: [this.currentPatient.nextKins['kinMobile']],
      kinEmail: [this.currentPatient.nextKins['kinEmail']]
    });
  }

  addKin() {
    const control = <FormArray>this.patientForm.controls['nextKins'];
    control.push(this.initNextKin());
  }
```

Comment: Have you considered starting with the code from that post ... ensure it works ... then slowly modifying it to your specific scenario ... checking that it still works after each change you make?
Another option is to build a plunker that illustrates your problem so others can run and see the issue you are having.

Comment: Just came back here to get the link you posted for the example you used and it was gone?

Comment: Sorry, here's the link https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2. I like the plunker suggestion.